# How to Post/Create One to Many Requests in Express/Mongoose (embedded model)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so I am new to express and have been trying it out with Mongoose.
Here's my problem, I am trying to make a post request where new friends can be created but only to one user. Like one user can have ten friends.

User Schema -

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userName: String,
userMail: String,
userPassword: String,
friends: { 
   type: mongoose.Schema.types.ObjectId,
   ref: "friends" 
},
});
module.exports= express.model("User, userSchema")
```

Friends Schema -

```
const friSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
age: Number,
});

module.exports= express.model("friends, friSchema")
```

I've tried a lot to Post friends but doesn't seem work.

My current code is where Post new friends.

```
router.post("user/:userName/friends", async (req, res) => {
  const newMember = new User({
    friends: req.body.friends,
  });
  const foundMember = await Member.findOne({ userName: req.params.userName });
  try {
    const savedMember = await newMember.save();
    res.json(savedMember);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

this is the code Where I can post new Users (works)

```
router.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const newMember = new User({
    userName: req.body.userName,
    userMail: req.body.userMail,
    userPassword: req.body.userPassword,
  });
  try {
    const savedMember = await newMember.save();
    res.json(savedMember);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in user schema -

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName: String,
    userMail: String,
    userPassword: String,
    friends: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
});
```

Friend creation API -

```
router.post('user/:userName/friends', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const foundMember = await User.findOne({ userName: req.params.userName });
      if (!foundMember) return res.json({ message: 'User not found'})

      // bulk create friends
      const newFriends = await friends.insertMany(req.body.friends); // assuming friends is an array of object with key name and age
      const frieldIds = newFriends.map((friend) => friend._id);
      foundMember.friends = [...foundMember.friends, ...frieldIds];
      await foundMember.save();
      res.json(foundMember);
    } catch (err) {
      res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the support. I had one question-- What does this mean/do?         
`const frieldIds = newFriends.map((friend) => friend._id);
 foundMember.friends = [...foundMember.friends, ...frieldIds];`

Also is there a way to show the name, age  etc rather than the _id?

Comment: So, newFriends would be an array of object ([ { _id : 123, age : 12, name : 'a' }, { _id : 124, age : 15, name : 'b' } ]. But inside friends variable, we are only storing the '_id' not the object. so first map function will take the array of object and prepare an array `frieldIds`, with just Ids. frieldIds would be [123, 124]. Now, we use spread operator to push these values to already existing array. So spread operator will just append the values of `frieldIds` with `foundMember.friends`. Just read a bit more on map function & spread operator.